# Balancing pendulum using PID

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-ide, arduino-nano

[image]

Dear all, referring to the video at [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aGakNXhAIN8&ab_channel=SangNguyenDuc) on how to make a PID balancing pendulum as shown in the picture and the author also provided the arduino code in the video description. May I ask whether this arduino code can be used on my MPU6050 gyroscope without any modifications because the author in the video does not provide the model of the gyroscope used. I have also searched countless of arduino code on web on **balancing pendulum using propeller PID with a DC brushless motor (not 3 phase) and MPU6050 gyrocope**, but couldn't find any and I hope someone could show me some examples code.

Thank you and have a nice day!!

```
// Chuong trinh dieu khien cân bang thanh ngang Nguyen Duc Sang 24/05/2018
//---------------------------------------------------------------

//875=0
//530=90 do
#define SENSOR A1
#define CONTROL 6
#define dongco 7

  
   void setup() { 
       Serial.begin(9600);
       pinMode(SENSOR,INPUT);
       pinMode(CONTROL,OUTPUT);
       pinMode(dongco,OUTPUT);
   }
   double error = 0;
   double realAngle;
   double lastrealAngle;
   double
     kP = 1,
     kI = 0.005,
     kD = 0;
   double 
     P = 0, 
     I = 0,
     D = 0; 
   double PID;  
   double setPoint = 90;
   int controlPwm = 85; 
   long lastProcess = 0;
  void loop(){
     realAngle = map(analogRead(SENSOR), 1023, 0, -39.73, 229.47);
     //Serial.println(analogRead(SENSOR));
     //Serial.println('gia tri goc realAngle la');
     Serial.println(realAngle);
     Serial.println(setPoint);
    //PID
    error = setPoint - realAngle;
    //thoi gian lay mau
    float deltaTime = (millis() - lastProcess)/100.0;
    lastProcess = millis();
    // P
    P = error * kP;
    // I
    I += (error * kI) * deltaTime;
    // D
    D = (lastrealAngle-realAngle) * kD * deltaTime;
    lastrealAngle = realAngle; 
   // Sub pid
  PID = P + I + D;
  if (PID>255){
   PID=255;}
   
  controlPwm = (PID + 80); 
 
    
    analogWrite(CONTROL,controlPwm );
  
  }
```

Comment: Is that **all** your code?

Comment: This cannot be all of your code. Nearly everything important is missing. I guess you had a copy and paste error. But I guess the answer is no. It seems the code is using an analog sensor. From the video I would guess it has a potentiometer at the axle of the arm. So it doesn't use a gyroscope. For the MPU6050 you would see either a corresponding library being imported or the `Wire` or `SPI` library being used (since the MPU communicates through I2C or SPI). I can write an answer once you have included the complete code in your question

Comment: @chrisl, hi sir, these codes are from the video dessciption. May I ask if there are any code that do balancing pendulum using propeller PID with a DC brushless motor (not 3 phase) and MPU6050 gyrocope ? Have a nice day :)

Comment: Either way you have to include the full code in the question, because questions on this site should be self contained. So please copy the full code into the question

Comment: @chrisl, done :),  May I ask if there are any code that do balancing pendulum using propeller PID with a DC brushless motor (not 3 phase) and MPU6050 gyrocope ?

Answer (score 2):

The shown code does not use the MPU6050. Instead it uses a sensor with an analog output signal. From the image and the video I suspect, that this sensor is a potentiometer attached to the axle of the arm. So the analog value basically gives you a measure of the angle.

> have also searched countless of arduino code on web on balancing pendulum using propeller PID with a DC brushless motor (not 3 phase) and MPU6050 gyrocope, but couldn't find any

That's not really surprising to me, since that is a very specific search request. That assumes that someone did exactly what you want to do and also described it with the same words. Finding a ready-to-use code that way is highly unlikely and I don't have such a code either.

**What to do now?** You will have to develop the code yourself. First you should divide up your project in individual parts, like: Getting readings from the MPU6050, calculating a stable angle value from the readings (by combining gyro and accelerometer values), driving the DC brushless motor and controlling its speed, implementing a PID feedback loop.

When you are able to implement each individual part by itself you can put them all together to make your project. Each individual part can be researched way easier, because there are many people, who have done these things in their own projects. Also try searching for Arduino libraries for these parts. For example: There are libraries for using the MPU6050, which will handle all the communication to the sensor for you. A good way to find libraries is search for "Arduino library MPU6050" (replace "MPU6050" by whatever single thing you wanna implement, like PID or similar). And such libraries are often hosted at Github, so it is often also good to search for something like "github arduino MPU6050". Try keeping your search request short. Look at the results and assess, if the found libraries are fitting for your situation.

And as help and inspiration you can search for similar projects. A quick search for "Arduino mpu6050 balancing robot" did show promising results and a balancing robot is very similar to your project.